# Login to Google account using Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

```
        Connection.Response loginPage = Jsoup.connect("https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?elo=1")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        Document loginDocument = loginPage.parse();
        Element form = loginDocument.getElementById("gaia_loginform");

        Connection connection1 = Jsoup.connect("https://accounts.google.com/signin/challenge/sl/password")
                .cookies(loginPage.cookies())
                .method(Method.POST);

        Elements inputElements = form.getElementsByTag("input");
        for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
            String key = inputElement.attr("name");
            String value = inputElement.attr("value");
            if (value != null && key != null && !key.equals("")) {
                connection1.data(key, value);
            }

        }
        connection1.data("Email", "myemeailv@gmail.com");
        connection1.data("Passwd", "mypassword");

        // trying to load gmail
        Response response = connection1.execute();
        Connection.Response main = Jsoup.connect("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#inbox")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .execute();

        System.out.println(main.body());
```

In code above I'm trying to submit **gaia_loginform** form which can be found on Google login page programatically. On first step I load login page using GET method. On the second step I'm creation connection using loaded data from **gaia_loginform** form and submit form via POST.

As result I expect to see some error messages but only login page is returned without any errors. I know there could be some kind of API for Gmail manipulation, but now I'm just trying to login so far.

Comment: You can't do that.  You should use OAuth and Google's APIs.

Comment: Why? If it can be done via browser by human, I believe it can be done using Jsoup or Selenium.  Actually I'm trying to download google wallet orders report, there is no API for that.

Comment: Jsoup is not browser, it's very limited, selenium can do it, i think so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i know very little about selenium, so i dont talk about it. After enter email address and press next, google account will send some extra params to browser via ajax (for example:bgresponse), and they will be added to post params,not just previous params.

The reason you receive login page is because you send different request without proper cookies, and google redirect to login page.

```
 Connection.Response main = Jsoup.connect("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=wm#inbox")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .execute();
```

Comment: Well finally I managed to login using Selenium. Not sure why code above does not work, maybe because of mentioned by you parameters